# Any way to get the users home timeline and their user details in a single request?

Tags: twitter, rate-limiting

I have a Twitter "widget" on my site where I allow users to login and pull in their twitter details and home timeline. I'm using OAuth for this and I have a little concern over rate limiting. In my widget, I'm having to make 2 requests every time I need the latest data. One request for the users details (and latest status) (the top section of my widget), and a separate request for their home timeline (the bottom section of my widget). What I'm wondering is if there is a way to get both with a single request. It just seems like it's a waste of requests to have to do it twice. Any way to do this or is this something I need to make a feature request for to Twitter? Does anyone else think that it would make sense for Twitter to always return the latest user details with each API request/result?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is not to pull the user details with every refresh; cache it locally and only update the display of user details intermittently.  Or give your use an option so they can control their own rate limit usage.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do have a kind of a user settable rate limit by letting the user control how often the widget refreshes. I was just hoping I missed something in the API that would enable the user details to be returned with the home timeline request. It seems to me, that they should return the authenticated users details with every request. But maybe thats just me...

Answer (score 0):

There's no single API to return what you're looking for. You can ask them to add it but don't hold your breath :).